# Webcal on Android

Tags: android, calendar

I have a webcal feed with a calendar I would like to add to the user of my app's google calendar. I've tried searching around a lot to see if this is possible but haven't really gotten anywhere. I'm still relatively new to android development so bear with me if I'm missing something very easy!

Answer (score 0):

To subscribe to the calendar on your Android phone you need to subscribe to the appropriate calendar in the Google Calendar account that is associated with your phone. Once you have subscribed, the calendar should appear on the phone.
I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm a developer and would like to subscribe users of my app to the webcal

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change the url from webcal:// to http://? You could build it and use CSS to display http or https when users are using Android. Does it perform an import or subscribe?